# JQuery UI tabs unresponsive in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, user-interface

I have a page that uses JQuery UI tabs, they load OK (although whole page renders far slower in IE9) but very slow to click/hover in IE9.  The page is fine in Chrome/Firefox.  I do have some Ajax/Json loading various bits on the page and I have reduced that down but I can’t work out how to rectify this issue in IE9.  Is it simply because there are a lot of background JQuery going on and IE9 can’t cope?  Can anyone help?  I am hoping that it is something obvious that I have missed because at the moment I am looking at a complete redesign of the page...!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to this pretty soon after posting but thought I would put it back on here.  The reason for the unresponsiveness was because I was still using jquery.livequery.js.  This was having some kind of conflict as when I removed it everything worked far better.